# How to filter results from collection the $lookup in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i want to filter the result as the following in mongodb. I use $lookup to populate the result from another collection. Please check my following code
This code below is what i get

```
 {
            "_id": "5f3d563122de0730d0f6a754",
            "barcode": "1234",
            "productname": "Lays Packet",
            "brandName": "Lays",
            "productSize": "12",
            "price": "12",
            "quant": "12",
            "imageurl": "http://localhost:3000/images/imageurl-1597855281050.jpg",
            "remaining": "12",
            "creator": "3d943b957fb5db510d824c5cbd6e8f7d",
            "__v": 0,
            "source": [
                {
                    "_id": "5f3a9bbc325a074240a1a815",
                    "firstname": "test",
                    "lastname": "test",
                    "storename": "test",
                    "gst": "test",
                    "phoneNumber": 1,
                    "email": "1@demo.com",
                    "address1": "test",
                    "address2": "test",
                    "city": "test",
                    "state": "test",
                    "country": "test",
                    "zip": "1",
                    "password": "1",
                    "usertype": 3,
                    "unique_SHOP": "3d943b957fb5db510d824c5cbd6e8f7d",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        },
```

How to retrieve only unique_SHOP and zip from source listing.I want result like the one below with one or more fields

```
 {
    "_id": "5f3d563122de0730d0f6a754",
    "barcode": "1234",
    "productname": "Lays Packet",
    "brandName": "Lays",
    "productSize": "12",
    "price": "12",
    "quant": "12",
    "imageurl": "http://localhost:3000/images/imageurl-1597855281050.jpg",
    "remaining": "12",
    "creator": "3d943b957fb5db510d824c5cbd6e8f7d",
    "__v": 0,
    "source": [
        {
             "zip": "1",
            "unique_SHOP": "3d943b957fb5db510d824c5cbd6e8f7d",
            
        }
    ]
},
```

The query i use

```
   List.aggregate([
    {$match:
      { productname: { $regex: req.params.query,$options: "i" }}
    },
    { $lookup:{
          from: "suppliers",
          localField: "creator",
          foreignField: "unique_SHOP",
          as: "source"
        }
   },
  
  
  ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [$lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries),

- `$match` condition of `creator id`
- `$project` to display required fields

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "suppliers",
      as: "source",
      let: { creator: "$creator" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$creator", "$_id"] }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            zip: 1,
            unique_SHOP: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zzr36HxMc0T)

Comment: can you suggest some video/website that teach more combining operations in mongodb?

Comment: I think best site is [mongodb reference docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/), they have explained and provided example as per requirement base, otherwise it is up to you take any scenario or example that you want to do in aggregation and Stack Overflow is the best site for readymade solutions of the problems and requirements. you can search on google you will get lots of solutions from SO.

Comment: @PrinjuKoshyVaidyan are you sure? `unique_SHOP`  field is reference of `creator` field?

Comment: Ok so i am not able to accept your edit, someone edit reviewer will review it and accept.